# Why don't I have Tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a new Mac, and I installed Python maybe two or three months ago, the newest version. Recently, I've been trying to get Tkinter to work, and I installed the Tk/Tcl I was supposed to (the latest one, as of February 3 2015). Still, when I try to `import Tkinter` I get an error message saying that it cannot find the module. Is there anything to be done?

Comment: Given that you say you have the latest version of Python (Python 3.4), the module name has changed to `tkinter` from `Tkinter`

Comment: I feel like an idiot... thanks :P